# Moving a RAID-5 array from a dead HP ML350 G5 to an HP DL380

Tags: hp, raid5, hp-proliant

We have an HP ML350 G5 with a 3x72GB RAID5 array that we were in the process of decommissioning.  After shutting down the server and moving it, but prior to moving the data elsewhere, the server failed to boot--apparently a bad power supply.

(The data is *'nice to have'* and not mission critical.  As such, it was not in our backup plan.)

Rather than replace the power supply for a server we are decommissioning, I was wondering if it were possible to move the array to an existing HP DL 380, which has the same type of SAS drives.  The ML350 has an on-board E200i controller, and the DL380 has a P400 card.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you go from one HP controller to another that was made at the same time or more recently and has an up to date ROMPaq applied the array will move over just fine. Simply move the disks to the 380, they don't even need to be in the same drive slots as they store their array information on each disk.

One word of warning though, don't try to 'pre-configure' the 380's array controller, just stick the disks in and let it get on with it. It'll probably throw up quite a few messages when it boots but just leave it alone for at least 30 minutes, you may need to do a full reboot 2/3 times after this to stop the various messages.

If you let me know the exact controller details for the 350 and the 380 I'll see if I can add any more meat to the bone ok.

Comment: Ok, just checked everything and you're safe to just move the disks over. I would suggest you do a full firmware update across all components in the 380 first - this is now very easy via this; http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121516&prodNameId=3288134&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-a69a789f6bfc4b0fbe2d84c7c6

Comment: This worked out just nicely.  Thanks.  Especially for the firmware upgrade tip.  It went very very smoothly.

Comment: Great news, I've been dealing with Compaq/HP for over 20 years now and thoroughly trust their kit but this kind of work is never without 'butterflies' - well done.

Answer (score 0):

Genrally if your controller is a SMART Array controler, you can move an array from one controller to another one of the same or greater "level".

If the controller of dead ProLiant is on a dedicated card and not "on board" you could try to move both disks and SMART Array Controller.

It could be a good idea to ask to HP customer support or to an HP certified vendor if the array controllers you are moving from and to are compatible.